# Possible to use a Windows CTabCtrl similar to CPropertySheet and multiple CPropertyPages?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I've used `CPropertySheet` with multiple `CPropertyPages` to generate tabbed dialogs. Is there a way to place a `CTabCtrl` within a `CDialog` app, with each tab of the control acting like a `CPropertyPage`?

Comment: see also the more modern equivalents `CMFCPropertySheet` and `CMFCPropertyPage`

Answer (score 4):

No, a `CTabCtrl` is not a page-switcher. It's just eye-candy to make a page-switcher yourself.

You can place a `CTabCtrl` in any way you like, but you must manage the switching of "pages" yourself. The control acts basically just like a radio group. The `CTabCtrl` by itself does not know about "pages".

If you do that, the pages are typically implemented as child dialogs.

Comment: The more modern `CMFCTabCtrl` takes care of show/hide logic when switching tabs, among a bunch of other advantages. I implemented a somewhat long range of apps on MFC with lots of tab controls and I see no valid reason for nowadays to use the old and out-of-date `CTabCtrl`.